# make install self-overrides

Tags: makefile, installation, overriding

I have a large software project that compiles and installs lots of libraries and headers into the default GNU file structure,

```
/usr/include/
/usr/lib/<pkg-arch>/
```

etc. I just noticed by running

```
sort install_manifest.txt | uniq --count --repeated
```

that some subprojects happened to export header files with different content but the same filename into `/usr/include/`, essentially overriding all but one. Needless to say that this causes the weirdest errors when trying to use the installed software.

Is it possible to have `make install` fail on overrides?

Comment: It will depend on what `make install` does. You can figure out with `make --dry-run install`. If it uses the coreutils `install` utility you will have to create a wrapper `install` script because the coreutils' version does not support what you want. But, anyway, this will not completely solve your problem: some of your software will not work as expected. Depending whether you preserve the first or last version of conflicting files will just change which software works - if any - and which doesn't.

Comment: Are you running the make as root? It appears you are running the install as root.

Best practice is to run the make as a "normal" user and create a package for your system. Then, when installing the package, the package manager detects file conflicts and aborts the package installation.